Time dilation with variable time scale
Real science information: You have a ship that is capable of relativistic velocities. Your trip is 4 light years away and you are moving at 0.999 % the speed of light.
​According to the time dilation equation
$\Delta t′ = γ\Delta t = \Delta t / \sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}$
$\Delta t′$– Time that has passed as measured by a stationary observer (relative time);
$\Delta t$ – Time that has passed as measured by the traveling observer;
$\gamma$ – Lorentz factor;
$v$ – Speed of the traveling observer;
$c$ – Speed of light (299,792,458 meters per second).
​
For you on the ship the total trip would take a little over 4 years and for an observer on Earth the trip would take approximately 89 Years 5 Months 18 Days.
Next part: Same scenario as above with a twist. The ship has the ability to move between dimensions. In our dimension the above statement applies but in the other dimension time is moving at an infinitesimally slow rate.
Question: Would traveling in the other dimension make the time dilation better or incredibly worse?

Will the 89 years take less time or will the time dilation effects being blown way out of portions? (ie, a million years)

The other dimension's time flow is supposed to flow "slower" as in our real dimension, I take it?

Correct 1 year on Earth could equal a 1000 years in the other dimension.

0.999% is about 1/100 (exactly 0.009999). If the distance is 4 gungs and the speed is 0.00999 gungs per year then the time is distance / speed = 400.4 years. From where do you get 89? (And assuming that the question really wanted to say 99.9% of the speed of light, from the stationary observer's point of view the trip would take 4.004 years. In the frame of reference of a passenger of the ship it would be much less, of course.)

As @AlexP says, 0.999% of c, ie 0.00999 c barely counts as relativistic except for the purpose of very precise measurements.  Please clarify the starting conditions before moving into hypothetical alternative universes.  (Dimensions don't work that way.)  Also note that if you actually mean 0.999 c then the time dilation during the acceleration and (presumably) deceleration phases are non-trivial to quantify.

please read the tag description: you have picked 2 mutually exclusive tags. Only one can stay.

At relativistic speed ($0.99c$), the coordinate trip time (perspective of Earth) should be about four years and proper trip time (perspective of ship) should be much less. At barely-relativistic speed ($0.99%c=0.0099c$), the coordinate trip time and proper trip time should both be about 400 years. None of the cited figures in the question are correct.

Reduced c of other dimension applies.
If the other dimension has a slower time flow than our dimension but the ship is switching there, it will -probably, hard to say how trans-dimensional space flight works exactly- fly with the reduced amount of c in that dimension. This means the trip will take longer.
Since the ship in our dimension is "not there anymore" after the switch, you can suppose that the light emitted or reflected by the ship will continue its journey through space and can be observed, but it is only a mirage, a phantom ship. Its light will probably arrive earlier than the ship itself (given a straight/geodesic flight route), because the ship has to travel in the slower universe. It is also possible that the light just dissolves at some point and the phantom ship vanishes after some time.
Edit: I interpreted 0.999% as being 99% c, though. Didn't see the %.

High speed, late arrival
Time moving slower does not matter for any observer. Whether time goes blazingly fast or super slow, we experience no difference. We process information at the same speed, and any interaction happens at the same speed, relative to the observer. There is a difference between time lines though.
...........
. . . . . .
Above are the two time lines for each dimension. Each dot is the smallest time frame that anything can happen. One is slower than the other, so less events happen per time frame.
As time and space are linked, nothing really changes for that dimension. You can still go at the exact same speed as in the original dimension. It is always a measure of space travelled per unit of time, and it going slower does not impact it at all.
So what would happen?
In my optic, the people hopping dimensions would not see any difference. When they get back to the original dimension they will have travelled the same distance in the same time. The observer in the original dimension will see them arrive much later than expected though. If you say 'infinitesimal slow', probably much more than 89 years. So you've gone incredibly fast to get somewhere in the slowest time.
Maybe Han Solo found the reverse, where he could go to a fast dimension. Time and space are linked, so saying you did it in less than 12 parsec is as good as saying you did it in less time, relative to the observers of the original dimension.

Time dilation works by making the passengers on the ship experience slower time than a stationary observer.
From the point of view of a stationary observer, trip duration is simply distance divided by speed. From the point of view of a passenger on the ship, it is less; in the limit, as the speed becomes closer and closer to the speed of light the time experienced by a passenger on the ship becomes closer and closer to zero.
